# dir(lxml) doesn't show etree

Tags: python, lxml

From what I know dir function will produce all the variables and object present in that module. But when I do dir(lxml) it does not show etree in the list of variables and method. The output I get is

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'get_include']
```

But I can import etree using:

```
from lxml import etree
```

So how is etree defined so that it doesn't show up in dir function but can only be imported using the import statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lxml is a python package which inside has the etree source.

In that case you are importing the source from your i.e. python2.7/site-packages/lxml/

It's not actuall a method or variable from lxml

How to define a python package:

The only requirement in order for python to detect a package is to have a `__init__.py` file which you might have seen often. It's ok if the `__init__.py` file is empty but it has to exists. You can check this example http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-create-a-python-package/

**All you need to do is:**

1. Create a directory and give it your package's name.
2. Put your classes in it.
3. Create a `__init__.py` file in the directory.

Comment: can you give me an example how this is done. Lets say I want "a.py" to be lxml and "b.py" to be etree. How do I define these files.

Comment: The only requirement in order for python to detect a package is to have a __init__.py file which you might have seen often. It's ok if the __init__.py file is empty but it has to exists. You can check this example http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-create-a-python-package/
I edit the answer because it escapes the underscores

Comment: I edited the answer. Also take care overriding python standard lib. If you create a package named random it will override python randome module

Comment: thank you. Now I am clear about packages and modules in python.